# Is there a way to see a log of the backend commands issued by VC commands?

Tags: vc, vc-mode

I'd like to see the what commands are issued by the child process used by the various VC commands.  Is there a way to log them or collect them without modifying the VC code?

For example, I'd like to see what Git command(s) are issued when the `C-x v ~` key is typed to execute the `vc-revision-other-window` command for a Git backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `vc-post-command-functions` will probably get you the majority of them, but not necessarily all of them.

For instance, I note that `vc-git.el` uses its own internal `vc-git--call` for a handful of things (where presumably there was some problem with going via the standard channel).